# How to model a user's calendar events with firebase

Tags: database, mongodb, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have users, each user gets assigned 12 events(they can reschedule these events etc) every 2 months. Each event is an object with id, name, description, date, is completed.

I'm currently saving these events in the user's document so that I do only one document read. `events:[{events}*12]` after a year there will be 72 events in this array, and it would keep growing year after year.

I'm wondering, should I be concerned with the 1mb limit?
I'd like to preserve history, so that the user can also view events of the past.

Given that on the calendar at most you could see one months worth of events, and say I lazy loaded the previous month for speed, doing a subcollection for events would result to 12-24 document reads. I fear this would get expensive very quick.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I wouldn't be too concerned with the 1MB limit, that is still a lot of characters (roughly 1 million, although may be a bit less depending on data types) - so unless the descriptions could be incredibly long I think it's unlikely you will reach anywhere near those limits.

That being said, if it is a concern you could schedule a cloud function to periodically (perhaps every 3 months) to archive or move events to a subcollection that are no longer still of use, storing across more documents (to represent the quarter, or year, or whatever time period you decide on)